# Get minimum element in constant time

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Lets say I have an array A of size n, where 0 <= A[i] <= n.

Lets say I have 2 arrays Forward and Backward, size n, where:

```
Forward[i] =  index j where
              A[j] = min(A[i], A[i+1], ..., A[n-1])
```

and

```
Backward[i] = index j where
              A[j] = min(A[i], A[i-1], ..., A[0])
```

My question is:

- given A, Forward and Backward
- given 2 indexes *l* and *r*

Can I discover the index k such that A[k] = min(A[l], A[l+1], ..., A[r]) in constant time?

Comment: what is the point of having the `Forward` and `Backward` arrays? If both `A[0]` and `A[n-1]` are the minimum value (e.g `0`), those arrays are pretty useless, or do i miss something?

Comment: A is not sorted and the values dont need to be from 0 to n-1, they can be all 1 for example.

Comment: Wondering what's wrong with `std::min`.. of course your types have to have sane comparison operators, but the "find the minimum" bit is kind of a solved problem..

Comment: If they are not sorted arrays then no, finding the minimum value in constant time is not possible - that's what `std::priority_queue<Type, Container<Type>, std::greater<Type>>` is for.

Comment: my problem is finding the minimum using that 2 arrays

Comment: Consider an array that is flanked with -Infinity on both sides. Then the forward and backward arrays will point to their respective ends, and be useless. What's left is A, and you need O(n) to pick a minimum out of n unsorted elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Atleast not in O(1) time. A counter example is as follows. `0-based` indexing is used here. Let

```
index     = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
A         = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 6, 4, 2, 0}

Forward   = {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8}
Backward  = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8}
```

Now, if I ask you to get the index of the minimum value in range `[3, 7]`, how will you do it?

Basically they will be of no use to find in the range [a, b]

> if `forward[a] > b` and `backward[b] < a`.

Comment: damn you were 13 seconds faster ;)

Comment: people could act like both of you and answer instead of just downvoting for no reason.. thanks, it was clear enough

Comment: @tobi303 still  much slower than my comment

Comment: @Daniel was my comment not enough? You would have been better off deleting your question.

Comment: It would be enough but they answered my question, gave me an example and before your comment

Comment: @Daniel You probably got downvotes because this would have been pretty simple to counter with an example if you had tried with some well thought examples.

Comment: I was pretty sure it wasnt possible from some examples i had in mind, but as I really needed this to be possible, I came here to ask

Answer (score 3):

No you cant. A counter example is:

```
A        = {0, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 0}
Forward  = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
Backward = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
l = 1, k = 5
```

ie `Forward` and `Backward` are of no use in that case and you have to search the array which is `O(k-l)`.